# Creating a column from another column with a 3% increase SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named QUOTATIONS and a column named price. I am trying to create a new column named NEW_PRICE that is all the data from PRICE with a 3% increase. So far I have been unsuccessful at even adding the new column with:

```
ALTER TABLE QUOTATIONS
ADD COLUMN  NPRICE NUMBER(4);
```

Comment: Why not use an `UPDATE`  query after creating the column, to fill it with the data?

Comment: NUMBER is a strange thing to use as the type; what is the type of the original column?  edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table QUOTATIONS` and `select version()`

Comment: how do you want the result rounded?  do you want your new column to change whenever the original column changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *generated column*:

```
ALTER TABLE QUOTATIONS
ADD COLUMN  NPRICE NUMBER(4) AS PRICE * 1.03;
```